# how to merge with specific revisions

Tags: svn, merge

Suppose I have two branches, A and B. I have made many commits in branchA. I want to merge A onto B only for revision 10 and 12-14.
I know that if I do `svn merge -r9:10 /src/to/branchA`, it will pick r10 from A and merge onto B. But the problem is that I need to do it for the revision 12-14. Is there a way that I can run this in one svn merge?

```
A
r10
r11
r12
r13
r14
r15

svn merge -r9:10 /src/to/branchA
svn merge -r11:14 /src/to/branchA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the options `-r` and `-c` more than once, and even mix them:

```
svn merge -c10 -r11:14 /src/to/branchA
```